# SUM from two tables, sort by country and publisher

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sum

I have two different sales tables and i want to SUM the quantity and FEEs for storeX and storeY from book_sales(isa), with quantity from all sales in the financial_report(xo). Im having trouble with both, and i dont know which JOIN i should use. The quantity calculation does not give any results and the fee calculation gives a number that is way to high. What is wrong here?

Please check my procedure if you have time:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Report] @startDate VARCHAR(10), 
                                   @endDate   VARCHAR(10) 
AS 
    SELECT BB.name  AS 'Publisher', 
           Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN isa.report_source = 'storeX' 
                      or isa.report_source = 'storeY' THEN 
                 isa.quantity * xo.quantity 
               END) AS 'Total quantity', 
           Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN isa.sales_price > 69 
                      AND isa.report_source = 'storeX' THEN 
                 6 * 1.25 * isa.quantity 
                 WHEN isa.sales_price <= 69 
                      AND isa.report_source = 'storeX' THEN 
                 3 * 1.25 * isa.quantity 
                 WHEN isa.sales_price <= 19 
                      AND isa.report_source = 'storeX' THEN 
                 1 * 1.25 * isa.quantity 
                 WHEN isa.sales_price > 69 
                      AND isa.report_source = 'storeY' THEN 
                 6 * 1.25 * isa.quantity 
                 WHEN isa.sales_price <= 69 
                      AND isa.report_source = 'storeY' THEN 
                 3 * 1.25 * isa.quantity 
                 WHEN isa.sales_price <= 19 
                      AND isa.report_source = 'storeY' THEN 
                 1 * 1.25 * isa.quantity 
                 WHEN xo.sales_price > 69 
                      AND bb.country = 'NOR' THEN 6 * 1.25 * xo.quantity 
                 WHEN xo.sales_price <= 69 
                      AND bb.country = 'NOR' THEN 3 * 1.25 * xo.quantity 
                 WHEN xo.sales_price > 69 
                      AND bb.country <> 'NOR' THEN 6 * xo.quantity 
                 WHEN xo.sales_price <= 69 
                      AND bb.country <> 'NOR' THEN 3 * xo.quantity 
               END) AS 'Fee inc VAT(tot)' 
    FROM   book_sales AS isa 
           INNER JOIN store AS BV 
                   ON bv.store_id = isa.store_id 
           INNER JOIN financial_report AS xo 
                   ON xo.identifiers = isa.identifiers 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN publisher AS BB 
                        ON bb.publisher_id = bk.publisher_id 
    WHERE  isa.sales_date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @startDate, 20) 
           AND isa.sales_date < Dateadd(day, 1, ( CONVERT(DATETIME, @endDate, 20 
                                                  ) )) 
    GROUP  BY bb.name, 
              bb.country
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems to sort out :

1- The total might be affected by NULL values, I suggest:

```
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN isa.report_source = 'storeX' 
                  or isa.report_source = 'storeY' THEN 
             isnull(isa.quantity,0) * isnull(xo.quantity,0)
             ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total quantity',
```

2- The case evaluation should be in order. For example:

```
             WHEN isa.sales_price <= 69 
                  AND isa.report_source = 'storeX' THEN 
             3 * 1.25 * isa.quantity 
             WHEN isa.sales_price <= 19 
                  AND isa.report_source = 'storeX' THEN 
             1 * 1.25 * isa.quantity
```

<= 19 will never happen because it is also <= 69 and therefore the <=69 will evaluate true.

3- Cardinality between tables might be 1 to many so the values are summed multiple times when they shouldn't. You may need to select distinct or aggregate or flatten out some of the tables in the join to avoid this issue.

Comment: Hey Jayvee thank you for helping.. i tried changing the quantity query. Still getting alot of wrong results and NULL values...

Comment: you may need to use isnull(columnx, 0) on every column that might contain null values; also you will need to add the ELSE 0 for the cases where nothing evaluates to true. This should sort the null problem.